# Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement

Tags: java

```
public class SumLineTester {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       SumLine test = new SumLine("5 8 3 2 1");
       System.out.println(test.getSum());
    }
}


import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumLine {
    private String line;

    public SumLine(String s) {
        line = s;
    }

    public int getSum(){
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner chop = new Scanner(line);

        while(chop.hasNextInt()){
            sum= sum + chop.nextInt();
        }
        return sum;

    public String getLine(){
        return s;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return line;
    }
 }
 }
```

The first portion of code above import is my tester class that contains my main method. The rest is the code that I am trying to run off of tester and I keep getting this error:

```
Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement

at SumLine.getSum(SumLine.java:17)
at SumLineTester.main(SumLineTester.java:10)
```

How do I fix the bug?

Comment: Check your braces. You can't declare methods within methods.

Answer (score 5):

Not at all sure why people think it is appropriate to downvote a question for some reason thinking the question is beneath them or such.  This is a perfectly valid question.  Even the most experienced programmers make syntactical errors.  It so happens I was lead here for a similar error, a ";" to terminate an annotation line which resulted in the same message.

The ***Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement*** seems to be a default error message for is a syntax error was made which confused the compiler badly enough that it could not tell what you were trying to do.  Once I understood this, was easy to spot that I ended a line with a ; that I should not have, and if/when I see this message again I will know it means I made a rookie syntax error and will no the class of error to look for.  Such an explanation would have helped this user, and if such an answer is beneath users, bypass the question please.  Downvotes are for bad questions and answers, not for questions on errors that you are too good to ever make.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the close brace at the end of your `getSum()`

```
public int getSum(){
    int sum = 0;
    Scanner chop = new Scanner(line);

    while(chop.hasNextInt()){
        sum= sum + chop.nextInt();
    }
    return sum;
^ \\no close brace

public String getLine(){
    return s;
}
```

This throws the exception because you are trying to declare a new method inside your `getSum()` method which is not allowed.

Just add the close brace in like this:

```
public int getSum(){
    int sum = 0;
    Scanner chop = new Scanner(line);

    while(chop.hasNextInt()){
        sum= sum + chop.nextInt();
    }
    return sum;
}
^ \\close brace added

public String getLine(){
    return s;
}
```

Also, as David Wallace noted in the comments, don't forget to remove the extra curly bracket at the end of your class.

As a side note, if you use an IDE like Eclipse, these errors are a bit easier to spot.

Comment: Of course, you also want to remove the leftover brace at the end of the file.

Comment: I thought that might go without saying, but good point :). Thank you and added.

Comment: My code works now. I had to sort out a few variable bugs, but its all good. I'm still a little irritated that I showed my code to three people before I went to StackOverflow and none of them saw it (including me). Thank you for the help though, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System. in)  //

    System.out.print("Enter first num:");
    int numOne = scn.nextlnt(); 
    System.out.print("Enter second num:");
    int numTwo = scn.nextlnt();
 
       System.out.println(" Sum : " + numOne + numTwo))
    System.out.println(" Difference : " + numOne - numTwo))
    System.out.println(" Product : " + numOne * numTwo))
    System.out.println(" Quotient : " + numOne / numTwo))
    System.out.println(" Remainder : " + numOne % numTwo))
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: please try to explain what you did, and why it should be done like that, so people reading this will get what and why the code is like this. try add some comments or explanation